# Customize axes in Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am a beginner with Python, Pandas and Matplotlib. I would like to customize the entries at the axes of a scatter plot. I have the following data:
[image]

So on the x-axis there should be 5 entries, with the first one being w1=1.0, w2=0.0. The 1 and 2 should be subscipts and w1 and w2 should be beneath each other, like you can see in the screenshot. Is there a way how to do this with pandas and matplotlib?

Here is the data (without the correspoding weight, you can see them in the screenshot):

```
Method 1    31.7    32.9    33.7    34.4    35.2
Method 2    44.2    45.4    46.9    48.9    45.5
Method 3    75.6    72.2    69.2    67.4    63.6
Method 4    87.5    83.2    79.5    77.8    72.2
Method 5    88.6    84.1    80.7    79.6    74.5
Method 6    100.0   100.0   100.0   100.0   100.0
```

The diagramm should look similar to this one, except that the description on the x-axis should be as I wrote above (instead of 1,2,3... to have w1=1.0, w2 =0.0, w1 =0.75, w2=0.25...)
[image]

EDIT: Here is the figure after applying the code of "Ignoring_Gravity". The are two things wrong. First, the order of the w on the x-axis (is supposed to start from w1=1, w1=0.75, ... , w1=0). Secondly, the points are on the wrong horizontal position. They should be right above the corresponding entries at the x-axis.[image]

Comment: Can you paste your table into the question, instead of putting a screenshot?

Comment: Hi Ignoring_Gravity, I just added the data

Comment: can you add the titles of the columns (w1 = , ...)?

Comment: Hi Ignoring_Gravity, you can see the titles on the initial screenshot. I could not manage to include them in the raw data set using the editing system of stackoverflow, because they were to long.

Comment: Really strange. There was an answer to my question that (almost) solved my problem, but I can't see it anymore. How come? Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can display subscripts by writing your column names using LaTex:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        0: {
            "Method 1": 31.7,
            "Method 2": 44.2,
            "Method 3": 75.6,
            "Method 4": 87.5,
            "Method 5": 88.6,
            "Method 6": 100.0,
        },
        1: {
            "Method 1": 32.9,
            "Method 2": 45.4,
            "Method 3": 72.2,
            "Method 4": 83.2,
            "Method 5": 84.1,
            "Method 6": 100.0,
        },
        2: {
            "Method 1": 33.7,
            "Method 2": 46.9,
            "Method 3": 69.2,
            "Method 4": 79.5,
            "Method 5": 80.7,
            "Method 6": 100.0,
        },
        3: {
            "Method 1": 34.4,
            "Method 2": 48.9,
            "Method 3": 67.4,
            "Method 4": 77.8,
            "Method 5": 79.6,
            "Method 6": 100.0,
        },
        4: {
            "Method 1": 35.2,
            "Method 2": 45.5,
            "Method 3": 63.6,
            "Method 4": 72.2,
            "Method 5": 74.5,
            "Method 6": 100.0,
        },
    }
)
df.columns = [
    "$w_1=1.0$\n$w_2=0.0$",
    "$w_1=0.75$\n$w_2=0.25$",
    "$w_1=0.5$\n$w_2=0.5$",
    "$w_1=0.25$\n$w_2=0.75$",
    "$w_1=0.0$\n$w_2=1.0$",
]

COLOURS = ['blue', 'green', 'red', 'yellow', 'pink', 'black']

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 8))
for n, (label, data) in enumerate(df.iterrows()):
    ax.plot(data, marker='o', linestyle='none', label=label, c=COLOURS[n])
ax.grid()
ax.legend(loc="best")
```

This'll give you:

[image]

You can pass different colours by changing what's in the `COLOURS` object.

Comment: Thanks Ignoring_Gravity, this helpled to fix the issues with the subscipts. Unfortunately there are still two furher issues (that I posted yesterday here). I uploaded the erroneous plot that I get, when using your code in Jupyter and added a short descpition of it in my previous post

Comment: No idea why you're getting a different plot from mine using the same code :) What versions of pandas and matplotlib are you using? Can you do `pip install --upgrade pandas matplotlib`?

Comment: Hi Ingoring_Gravity, I tried to use your comment within Anaconda prompt (I ran is as an Administrator) and I received the following error message:"ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Zugriff verweigert: 'c:\\users\\wi9632\\appdata\\local\\continuum\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\matplotlib\\backends\\_backend_agg.cp36-win_amd64.pyd'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions."

Comment: You can either do `pip install --upgrade pandas matplotlib --user`, or you can create a conda environment and do it in there, see https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html

Comment: Oh man, this is really getting frustrating. I did what you told me with the command "pip install --upgrade pandas matplotlib --user" and I did not get an error message. However, when I start Jupyter now and run your code I get an new error: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.artist'"

Comment: @PeterBe OK, let's create a conda environment and do it in there. From the anaconda prompt, type "conda create -n myenv python=3.7" (you can replace myenv with another name if you prefer). Then, "conda activate myenv". Then, "pip install --upgrade pandas matplotlib"

Comment: Again an error message: (C:\Users\wi9632\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3) C:\Users\wi9632>conda create -n myenv python=3.7
Fetching package metadata ...........

PackageNotFoundError: Package missing in current win-64 channels:
  - python 3.7*

Comment: Did you install conda some time ago? Might need to upgrade it: "conda update conda", "conda update anaconda". Alternatively, you could try to use "python=3.6" instead of "python=3.7" in the previous command

Comment: I did  "conda update conda" and "conda create -n myenv python=3.7"  and it was okay. But the command "conda activate myenv" leads to the error message "CommandNotFoundError: 'activate'"

Comment: Can you try closing and re-opening anaconda prompt? Else, try `source activate myenv`

Comment: I just re-opened anaconda and can now see the new myenv environment. If I start a terminal within this environment I get the same error message. Also "source activate myenv" with the error message "The instruciton source is either spelled wrong or could not be found" (translated from German)

Comment: I think this is a separate issue, you might want to ask a new question about that and then come back to this when your environment is sorted out

Comment: Now I reinstalled Anaconda and the figure looks good :-). Thanks a lot Ignoring_Gravity. Still there are two further questions that I have. First: Is there a simple way how to adjust the color for each of the methods. Second: On the x-axis after one entry there comes an empty tick. How can I get rid of this while still having some distance between the ticks.

Comment: @PeterBe sure - I've updated the solution. Sorry this has taken so long, I'm relatively new to answering questions!

Comment: Thanks a lot again Ignoring_Gravity for your effort. As I not only want to copy and paste the answers but also to learn from them, I have to admit that I do not understand the following lines:'fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 8))' and
'for n, (label, data) in enumerate(df.iterrows()):
    ax.plot(data, marker='o', linestyle='none', label=label, c=COLOURS[n])'. Would you mind elaborating on them? What "does fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 8))" do and why is there a , between fig and ax. What does the loop "for n, (label, data) in enumerate(df.iterrows())" do.

Comment: `n` in just a counter from `0` to `6`, and it lets us choose the relevant colour. `fig` is a matplotlib figure, `ax` is a subplot - please refer to the [user guide](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-introductory-usage-py)