# Creating new Anaconda environment

Tags: python, anaconda

I have problems creating a new Anaconda environment. I am new to Python and Anaconda and in another thread ([Customize axes in Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59561768/customize-axes-in-matplotlib)) I was asked to create an new environment because apparently I was using an old version of some packages (Pandas, Matplotlib and also from Jupyter).

So I inserted the following comments in the Anaconda prompt:

```
conda update conda
conda create -n myenv python=3.7
```

Both of them could be executed without an error and a new environment was created in Anaconda. I was further told to use the following comment:

```
conda activate myenv
source activate myenv
```

Both of them lead to error messages. The first one leads to the message "CommandNotFoundError: 'activate'" and the second one to "The instruciton source is either spelled wrong or could not be found" (translated from German). The helping person from the other thread told me to ask this in a separate question because, he or she does not know, what the problem might be. Does anyone of you have an idea.

Comment: what is your conda version ?

Comment: Anaconda Navigator 1.6.2

Comment: No, that's the GUI. Go to terminal and type `conda --version`

Comment: The version is "conda 4.3.30"

Answer (score 3):

You version is old. Please update your conda to the latest version. Then `conda activate myenv` would work. You can update by running the following command in your terminal:

`conda update conda`

Comment: Thanks YOLO for the answer, if I use your command I get the following error message: "CondaEnvironmentNotFoundError: Could not find environment: base .
You can list all discoverable environments with `conda info --envs`." If I use the command "conda update -n myenv -c defaults conda" I get the following error "PackageNotInstalledError: Package is not installed in prefix."

Comment: @PeterBe I think the version you have is so old it was from when Anaconda called the **base** env **root** instead. So, `conda update -n root -c defaults conda` might do the trick. Essentially, you can only install the `conda` Python *package* in the default environment (called **base** or **root**, depending on the version). You can also check your env names with `conda env list`.

Comment: Thaks merv for your answer. I get the same error message, when I use your code. Also I can't see in the GUI how to update Anaconda.

Comment: @YOLO: I used the command "conda update conda" and I get the error message "PackageNotInstalledError: Package is not installed in prefix.
  prefix: C:\Users\wi9632\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\myenv
  package name: conda". This is strange because I remember that this command did work some hours ago in the old environment (as  stated in the initial post)

Comment: Any idea why this is not working and I get error messages when I use the code suggested by YOLO "conda update conda"

Comment: Looks like you have two different terminal, try in anaconda terminal. are you using windows ?

Comment: Yes I have windows. What I basically do is to open the GUI of Anaconda. Then on the left side I click on "Environment". Afterwards I click on the environment "myenv" on the arrow and then on "Open Terminal"

Comment: instead go to windows search option, type 'terminal' and it will show 'anaconda prompt'

Comment: Okay, I could open the terminal and now I get a new error message after some time: "ERROR conda.core.link:_execute_actions(337): An error occurred while installing package 'defaults::tqdm-4.40.2-py_0'.
CondaError: Cannot link a source that does not exist. C:\Users\wi9632\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe
Running `conda clean --packages` may resolve your problem.
Attempting to roll back." I also exectued `conda clean --packages` but this did not help. The problem still occurs

Comment: @PeterBe at this point you might be better off uninstalling and reinstalling Anaconda - or just using [miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html)